# Error Installing TensorFlow on Rasperry Pi 3 B

Tags: pi-3, python, raspbian-stretch, python-3, pip

I'm following [this](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/ai-chatbot/) guide to create an AI chatbot which requires Python 3.6, TensorFlow etc. So I installed Python 3.6.8.

To install TensorFlow I tried `sudo pip install tensorflow`

I also downloaded the .whl file and tried `sudo pip install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-none-linux_armv7l.whl`

I also tried using pip3.6 `sudo pip3.6 install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-none-linux_armv7l.whl`

All of them return the same error.

```
  Loading library to get version: libhdf5.so
  error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/ tmp/pip-install-v9ml238y/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file __);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, ' exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-m8i6i3k3/install-record.txt --single-v ersion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-instal l-v9ml238y/h5py/
```

Sorry for any mistakes. This is my first post.

Comment: Try to install the library : `sudo apt-get install hdf5 libhdf5-dev` ?

Comment: I think you mean ```sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev```

Comment: yes but `libhdf5-dev` contain dev headers files. The library (.so) itself must be in a package `libhdf5-X` where X is the version. You can find the lib with : `sudo apt-cache search libhd5` for example you can have `libhdf5-100`.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libhdf5-100 : HDF5 is a file format and `library` for storing scientific data

Comment: Hi AnonyoZarif, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. A couple of months ago I tried to install TF but failed because of the "failed to build h5py error" error. I am not sure if it is related to "hd5" thing mentioned by @Ephemeral. In the same Q&A, #Kor mentioned that he finally solved the problem, but I still got stuck. Anyway, I have stalled my project and waiting for google to update. Here are the links for your reference, in case you are interested. Good luck and cheers. (1) Rpi4B TensorFlow Installation Record - tlfong01 2019sep30
https://penzu.com/public/3970e2d0

Comment: (2) Error Installing Tensorflow in Raspberry Pi 4 - 2019sep26 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103983/error-installing-tensorflow-in-raspberry-pi-4/103996#103996

Comment: I read my penzu installation record and noticed the last line says the following:
“error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory”. So @Ephemera seems to have solved my problem. But now I am tied up playing with other toys to resume my stalled installation.. I would much appreciated it if you can help looking into it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I have solved my problem. I reinstalled Python 3.6.

Then I used this command `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev` and then `sudo pip install tensorflow` and installed TensorFlow successfully!

I think the problem was with my Python installation.

Thanks to all of you for your kindness. Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes, I did complain that GG TF installation was once wrong and misleading.  They said your could not use PIP2 for Python 3, and if you did you will get a mess.  But they did not said so before hand.

Comment: Yes you are right but i used pip3.6

Comment: A long time ago (I can't remember when) I also tried to install TF with pip2 and as usual- it failed.

Comment: Okay @Ingo doing it