# Error installing Tensorflow (cannot find libhdfs.so)

Tags: pi-4, packages

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and after a week I have accomplished nothing because I can't get TensorFlow installed.

Hoping someone can PLEASE help me.

My error message:

```
E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I thought I found the solution from the link below but it didn't solve my issue:

[Error Installing Tensorflow in Raspberry Pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103983/error-installing-tensorflow-in-raspberry-pi-4)

```
(newenv) pi@raspberrypi:/newenv $ python3 
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2020-01-19 13:55:24.896587: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
I have reinstalled NOOBS 3 times to start "fresh" after tinkering with all of the online solutions...

Update:  Instead of using NOOBS I used Raspian Buster with desktop and recommended software.  Same Hadoop error message.

Thanks.

Comment: [Have you tested this one? Worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43490524/6602159)?

Comment: Or this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106917/error-installing-tensorflow-on-rasperry-pi-3-b.

Comment: I am a little bit confused.  It appears that you are trying to import tensorFlow in a python 3.7.3 shell. But have you successfully installed tensorFlow earlier? The links you and me referred are about tensorFlow installation problems and two examples on how to solve the problems and finally successfully installed tensorFlow. In other words, you must first successfully install tensorFlow, BEFORE you can start a python shell and import the tensorFlow module.

Comment: This is what I have done.  1) I reinstalled NOOBS. 2) Then I downloaded tensorflow using this command sudo pip3 install tensorflow (from https://www.piwheels.org/project/tensorflow/) from the command window.  It downloaded without any errors.  3)  I type in Python3 to get the Python shell then type in import tensorflow and I get the following error message.  E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @M.Rostami I searched my files and I don't even have a libhdfs.so  How can I not have it?  Shouldn't it be installed when I download Tensorflow.  Hmmm. Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't use comments for further explanations. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107483/edit) your question and add it there. What operating system do you install from NOOBS? Do you use Raspbian?

Comment: @M.Rostami I updated my question above to answer your question.

Comment: @user2607686 Try `>>> import tensorflow as tf`. Some people have the problem same as you. Please refer to [#36141](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36141) and if that doesn't solve your issue, open a new one on the [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Answer (score 10):

Hey I recently figured this out. Here's a YouTube video I made giving the step-by-step: https://youtu.be/GNRg2P8Vqqs

Installing Tensorflow requires some extra steps on the Pi's ARM architecture.

This is how I installed tf on my Pi 4:
Make your project directory:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir tf_pi
cd tf_pi
```

Make a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Run the commands based on https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/#usage:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libc-ares-dev libeigen3-dev
python3 -m pip install keras_applications==1.0.8 --no-deps
python3 -m pip install keras_preprocessing==1.1.0 --no-deps
python3 -m pip install h5py==2.9.0
sudo apt-get install -y openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev
python3 -m pip install -U six wheel mock
```

Pick a tensorflow release from https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases (I picked 2.0.0). Picking a higher version of Tensorflow (like 2.1.0) requires a higher version of scipy that wasn't compatible with my Raspberry Pi:

```
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.0.0/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

RESTART YOUR TERMINAL

Reactivate your virtual environment:

```
cd Desktop
cd tf_pi
source env/bin/activate
```

Test:
Open a python interpreter by executing:

```
python3 
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

This should have no errors and output: 2.0.0